# Sending an event from a thread to a UI

Tags: c#, multithreading

Apologies as I know cross-thread operations have been addressed elsewhere, but all I see are fragments and can't quite figure out where to apply the solutions correctly. So I have distilled this problem to it's most basic essence in the hope that me and anybody else who comes across this can see a complete solution without a lot of support code to wade through or fragments with limited context.
I have looked at various posts such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356/cleanest-way-to-invoke-cross-thread-events), [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/886223/csharp-multithreading-and-events) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135430/sending-events-to-a-specific-thread) but can't quite place the solutions in context.

I have created a Windows Forms project with a single button and textbox. In the form.cs file here is the complete code to demonstrate the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace SampleEventTest
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            TestClass();
        }).Start();
    }
    private void TestClass()
    {
        TestEvent tv = new TestEvent();
        tv.OnClsConnect += new TestEvent.clsConnect(OnConnected);
        tv.DoSomethingThread();
    }
    public void OnConnected(string str)
    {
        textBox1.Text = str;
    }
}
public class TestEvent
{
    public delegate void clsConnect(string str);
    public event clsConnect OnClsConnect;

    public void DoSomethingThread()
    {
        if (OnClsConnect != null)
        {
            OnClsConnect("Thread run");
        }
    }

}
}
```

Click the button and you will get the "Cross thread operation not valid" error. How does one properly fix this code? TIA

Comment: You have to tell that you want to execute code on UI thread. In order to do that you invoke method `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke` which executes a job on UI thread. All of this is because UI elements can only be updated from UI thread. This is by design and you have to stick to it.

Comment: The marked duplicate, which comprehensively addresses cross-thread scenarios in Winforms, has as its accepted and highest-voted answer, a code example that is no less direct and clear than the one you posted below.

Comment: I looked at the example you posted. It is a code snippet, precisely what I was trying to avoid here. In addition mine has a separate class as opposed to just another thread. I respectfully disagree.

Comment: Actually the only method you should be concerned with is `void OnConnected(string str)`. And handling UI properties is very well described in the duplicate. You cannot avoid invoking dispatcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H/T to S.A. Parkhid for this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls).

Here is the solution: modify the method OnConnected to the following:

```
    public void OnConnected(string str)
    {
        if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            var d = new TestEvent.clsConnect(OnConnected);
            textBox1.Invoke(d, new object[] { str });
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = str;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use the BackgroundWorker Control. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLrrbG6V1zM) is a quick link. also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481304/how-to-use-a-backgroundworker) is an anther link which helps you.

also please read this:

[How to: Make thread-safe calls to Windows Forms controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls)